# Motorizing Hobby Train 10183

Tags: motor, trains, customization

What are the PF motors available that will power the Hobby Train 10183?

Moving out from 9v tracks, will the existing 10183 wheels fit any other tracks?

Also, is there a difference between the PF motors used for the Technic models and for the train sets?

Much obliged for your help. This is my entry into Lego trains.

Answer (score 2):

The motor used in Hobby Trains is the [9V train motor](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=10153-1). This motor is externally identical to the new [Power Functions train motor](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=88002-1), so you should be able to replace one with the other.

That said, the problem with Power Functions is that where in 9V it was enough to have the train motor mounted on the train, in PF you will also need to provide an IR receiver and a battery pack. You would need to modify each Hobby Trains model to have it house those components and the connecting wires (one of which should go through the floor of the train to the PF Train motor, so you need a hole in the floor). Net, it will require some creativity, and some Hobby Trains models are better suited to this adaptation than others.

Answer (score 1):

As Phil notes, the [PF train motor](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/LEGO-Power-Functions-Train-Motor-88002) is exactly what you are looking for:

[image: PF train motor]

You'll also need one of the PF battery boxes and an IR receiver. You will need to modify the trains themselves to house the extra components and make room for the wires.

In response to your second question, 9V, RC, and PF train track is all functionally identical. The only significant difference is the conductors on the 9V rails.

In regards to the PF system, the Technic motors and train motors use the same electrical connections, but they are physically different shapes.

Comment: Thanks so much! Also, is there a difference between the PF motors used for the Technic models and for the train sets? I'm really new to this, and really appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem. I've updated your question and my answer to explain this. Feel free to create a new question if you have additional questions.